# should we just derive both the put option equation and the call option?

Tags: finance

under these assumption The Black-Scholes assumptions below are made in this problem:
 (1) calls and puts are European style;
(2) both the call and the put share the same underlying, which is none-dividend paying; 
(3) expiry ܶstrike ܭ ,and interest rate ݎ are the same for both the call and the put.

show
that the call and the put share the same vega, i.e., please prove the following equality.

݀
= ଴ܥ ߪ݀
݀
଴ܲ ߪ݀[image]

Comment: Start from the Put-Call parity.

Comment: is there a way we dont use the call put parity to prove it ?

Comment: You can do it directly, just by computing the derivative of the option formula with respect to the volatility.